# More than one point query to Azure storage service

Tags: azure, storage, point

I have a question about point queries in Azure. If I have a huge number of Partition key/Row key pairs is there a smart way to make a huge number of point queries to fetch the entities?

I can of course iterrate through the n pairs and make n queries but I feel there is a smarter way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer from [Joe Giardino, Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/5160b393-6f40-4354-86a0-8357cb6cf5d6/best-way-to-select-different-unrelated-records-using-rowkey):

> If you want several non contiguous row keys, then issuing separate but
>   parallel individual queries of below form will perform better. When
>   you specify both PartitionKey and RowKey the query is considered a
>   "PointQuery" which is the most performant option.

```
 a) PartitionKey == “MyPK” && RowKey == “FirstRK”
 b) PartitionKey == “MyPK” && RowKey == “SecondRK"
```